# Why does Superman wear a cape (in-universe?)

Tags: dc, comics, superman

Superman has worn a cape since his first appearance and was perhaps the man who made the concept of capes popular.

A scene from *The Incredibles*, specifically the one with Edna and her general dislike of capes, made me wonder why Superman wears a cape.

Batman wears it because it acts as a part-time glider of sorts, and yes this question could be asked for the numerous other heroes (Shazam, Homelander, Black Adam, etc.), but since Superman popularized the trope I ask about him.

I have read that he wore it because it was a part of Kryptonian culture, because it healed him, and because Martha just made him wear it.

Is there any actual reason why Superman wears a cape in-universe?

Comment: So that super villains can grab him with it; same as with Batman.

Comment: Are we talking strictly the golden age comic book Superman here ( who popularized the concept) or any Superman. There reasons might not always be the same.

Comment: Because capes are cool

Comment: Because Zoro wore a cape.

Comment: Case in point: [Dollar Bill](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194541/7957).

Comment: Because his Mom made it so he *better* wear it.

Comment: Same reason he uses this whole costume.

Comment: Related:  ["How did Martha Kent modify the Kryptonian blanket that became Superman's costume?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/how-did-martha-kent-modify-the-kryptonian-blanket-that-became-supermans-costume).

Comment: Guessing that the out-of-universe reason was so Superman could have a tight, form-fitting costume -- reminiscent of strong-men and wrestlers -- without showing his butt-crack every time he turned around.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Does-Supermans-cape-have-a-function-or-is-it-just-a-vanity-piece

Comment: Because without it streaming out behind him in the publicity shots, people would think he had just been photoshopped into the sky.

Comment: Related: [Why did Jonathan and Martha Kent attach a Cape to Superman's costume?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25123/why-did-jonathan-and-martha-kent-attach-a-cape-to-supermans-costume)

Comment: @wyvern I think that's a good dupe candidate. The answer seems to give out-of-universe and in-universe reasons as to the _whys_ of the cape.

Comment: Because it hides – at least from behind – the fact that he’s put his underwear on outside his trousers.

Comment: If you've ever worn a cape at Halloween or a party, you'd know how cool they feel.

Answer (score 21):

**TO PROTECT OTHERS**

Superman has on numerous occasions used his cape to protect people from bullets, explosions and whatnot. The Silver Age Superman also used to wrap Lois Lane in his cape when flying her to the Fortress of Solitude. See pictures below.

There may be other reasons, but this one, at least, is very well documented.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, Batman and Robin have done so too to a lesser extent, as far as I can remember.

Comment: Now the question is: was it an intended feature of the cape, or was it just a conveniently jury-rigged feature?

Comment: @Clockwork: I had exactly the same question :) I have the feeling that in the picture above, the cape is used simply because it is a lot more visible than an energy field (literally invisible). Thus, more dramatic effect.

Comment: As I recall the cape originally had a pouch to hold his Kent clothing.

Comment: Maybe, @virolino, the cape is just the visible manifestation of Superman's energy field. ;)

Comment: In some versions, his mom Martha designed the costume. Maybe she was influenced by older super heroes like the Golden-age Green Lantern. Who was probably influenced by wrestlers and circus performers (who'd influenced Siegel and Shuster in the first place)

Comment: He's protecting *Lex Luthor* in that middle example?  That must've been a strange day...

Comment: can someone please explain the context of Luthor calling Superman "sir"

Comment: @shanu You might want to write a context/episode identification question

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson: In what sense is Golden-age Green Lantern "older" than Superman? I thought Green Lantern appeared in 1940, whereas Superman was wearing his cape on the cover of Action Comics #1 in 1938.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think there's a version where, in-universe, Superman was one of the "modern" heroes who debuted in the last few decades, but the WWII heroes like the original Green Lantern predated them.

Comment: Sometimes this works, sometimes this doesn't. I definitely remember in Superman  Annual #2 (1987) where  his cape was ordinary material, and was destroyed when a burning tanker truck he was lifting  into the air exploded, leaving the yellow S-Shield to flutter down and let the watching firefighters and policeman think Superman been killed. But In the early post-crisis era, the suit was ordinary cloth, and the cape stuck out of the field.

Answer (score 7):

**Aerodynamics**

In the CW [*Supergirl*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_(TV_series)) series, it is stated that adding a cape to her costume helps Supergirl maneuver more accurately in flight. Presumably the same would be true for Superman, but I don't have a source explicitly about him.

Comment: What is _CW_ supposed to mean?

Comment: @Clockwork The CW Television Network

Comment: That is, of course, stunningly wrong.  Cloth flapping in the wind induces *lots* of unequal drag forces.

Comment: @Clockwork CW is the result of a merger between UPN and WB (the latter standing for "Warner Bros"). At the time of the merger, UPN was owned by CBS, so the combined network was given the initials CW.

Comment: @RonJohn: that is unless the cape has turbo jet capabilities and embedded flaps ;) Since the cap cannot be controlled, it obviously cannot be used for... controlling the flight - unlike wings or tails.

Comment: @RonJohn I guess a "cape made from structured polymer composites" somehow negates that problem.

Comment: @Barmar call me crazy, or maybe an old grump, but "structured polymer composites" sounds like the technobabble version of "lignin".  Superman's cape is made of wood!

Comment: @Acccumulation. What about UPN?

Comment: @MadPhysicist United Paramount Network. And CBS is Columbia Broadcast Network (which is now a subsidiary of Paramount).

Comment: @RonJohn Exactly. The only cases I'm aware of where anything (aerodynamically) resembling a cape has been intentionally placed on an aircraft is that streamers are sometimes attached to (at least model) rockets _specifically for the purpose of slowing them down... a lot_. (i.e. used as a somewhat-lower-drag alternative to a parachute during recovery.)